# Create a local end-to-end development environment

Tags: docker, terraform

I am beginning to use [terraform](https://terraform.io/) to control staging and production environments on various cloud providers (AWS for example).  Is there a way to use terraform configuration files to create a local development environment for, say, a multi-tier application environment or do I have to maintain a different configuration via, say, vagrant for my development needs?

This may not be too difficult to do with two tools since most components are dockerized, but it would be nice to have a single configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a cross platform orchestration tool is that it ends up catering for the lowest common denominator in terms of features available on all clouds. Terraform just describes the infrastructure using the resources available from the desired provider.

So long story short you'll need separate configurations, but if you're deploying to a cloud there is nothing stopping you from using that for QA or acceptance test environments.

Comment: I suspect you mean the greatest common denominator.

Comment: What is the lowest common denominator of 30 and 10?